# How to fix "gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found." error while running "add-apt-repository"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, gcc

I want to install Criterion in my docker container. I use "gcc:9.1" as base image. The "add-apt-repository" shows the mentioned error, and "apt-get install" then fails. If I conduct these actions with an ubuntu image, everything works fine. For this reason, I think that there might be some missing dependency..

```
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:snaipewastaken/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends criterion-dev
```